# Error when trying to convert my date to datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, datepicker

Im using datepicker in my input to select the date.

Im my datepicker script I set a format to my date, like this:

```
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({

            dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy', 
        });
```

**The result** of this is "Wednesday, 30 April, 2014".

But now I want to save this text date in my sql table **as datetime** so I need to do the conversion.

Im Trying like this:

```
$f['date'] = $_POST['date'];
$newdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($f['date']));
echo $newdate;
```

But When I do the echo it shows always: "1970-01-01"

**My input:**

```
 <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format isn't one that `strtotime()` recognizes. Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead:

```
$newdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', 'Wednesday, 30 April, 2014');
echo $newdate->format('Y-m-d');
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Wpt5DM)